# Stormcrawler's ContentParseFilter

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

If I set StormCrawler's ContentParseFilter to be

```
"pattern": "//DIV[@id=\"site-body\"]",
```

does that mean that that is the ONLY place it will look for links to other pages when processing each url?  I am wondering if I set that if it will start ignoring all the urls in the menus and such.

Thanks!
Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [WIKI page for ParseFilters](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/wiki/ParseFilters)

> The ContentFilter allows to restrict the text of a document to the text covered by a Xpath expression

it does not affect the extraction of links at all but aims at improving the text indexed.